# Lazarus project window version convert

Tags: windows, platform, lazarus

I made a project on the lazarus IDE, I run it on my machine win 7 x84_64 and it was executed well, then my client tested it on his machine and it run too(win 7 x84_64), but after that he tried on a Windows XP but it did not run. He didn't catch the error, so I don't know what is the specific problem but I wonder it's about "window compatibility" Is there some way to compile my project for XP platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably creating 64bit applications with your 64bit Lazarus. You can also install 32bit Lazarus, and it's generated applications will run on both 32bit and 64bit Windows. You can also cross compile from 64bit Lazarus to 32bit Windows, but that is not trivial. For Lazarus cross compilation you can start **[here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling)**. If you want easy cross compilation, then take a look at Lazarus CT edition (also known as **[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/)**). It is packed with tons of components, 8 OS/CPU host layers (Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64, FreeBSD32, FreeBSD64, Solaris32, Solaris64), and 25 OS/CPU target layers. More info **[here](http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/index.html?codetyphon_current_status.htm)**.